# how to use visual studio report viewer to show reporting service reports

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

I create a reporting service project: "Report Project1" and add a report : "Report1.rdl" . I deploy this report to my local report server .I can see the report using my local report manager seb site.Now I want to see this report in my web site.I add `Report Viewer` to my page :

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Width="913px">
    <ServerReport ReportPath="Report Project1/Report1.rdl" ReportServerUrl="http://nima/ReportServer_SQL2008"/>
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

but when I run it I don't see any thing.what is the problem?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a slash before `ReportPath` and delete `.rdl` and set `ProcessingMode="Remote"` for `ReportViewer`